# HTML calling function using id

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, leaflet, addeventlistener

The html code below is calling a `plusSlides` function that activates an array just like this [example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp).

```
<div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="mySlides" id=test1>
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides" id=test2>
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides" id=test3 >
    </div>
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
```

Once the `plusSlides` array calls `mySlides` class, I want my leaflet layers to be added to the map. This is done when the user clicks on `prev` and `next`. Code below is an example of the javascript for test1:

```
document.getElementById("test1").addEventListener("toggle", waterMap);
function waterMap() {
    map.addLayer(watermainLayer);
}
```

**I am trying to add the toggle event listener for test1 so once the `mySlides` class has been called, waterMap function, which adds a leaflet layer to map, will activate. I am doing this wrong but do not know how to go about it. May someone help me?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I where you, I would take the simple solution: 
Add in the function showSlides(n)

```
if(n == 1) //change for the index wherever you wants
   waterMap();
```

I use like reference the link of the example you give us

Comment: Thank you! They layers are showing up once i click on next or prev!

Comment: Hey sixerss, once I call the layers through the specified index, the next button goes through all the layers but if I try to go left, it only goes through two of the three layers. Would you know why it isn't working?